# Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, option[value="xxx"])

Tags: visual-studio-code, protractor, e2e-testing

I just wrote my first e2e test with Protractor in VS Code. Here is a weird issue that has been bugging me for days. I keep getting this error from time to time. I noticed that sometimes when I shut down the VS Code and re-open it. The issue will be gone. However, it will come back after a while.

test.spec.ts

```
fit('should have an quote price', async () => {
  await page.fillApplicantAge(0, '20');

  const tobaccoUsageSelection = page.getRadioButton('smoker', 'no');

  await page.clickElement(tobaccoUsageSelection);

  const planTypeSelection = page.getNamedRadioButton('planType', 'Single');

  await page.clickElement(planTypeSelection);

  const coverageTypeSelection = page.getNamedRadioButton('coverageType', 'Gold');

  await page.clickElement(coverageTypeSelection);

  await page.fillApplicantEffectiveDate(0, 'today');

  await page.fillApplicantExpiryDate(0, 'next month');

  await page.setSelectBoxValueInsideChildComponent('destination', 'New York');

  await page.fillTextBox('sumInsured', '5500');

  const priceElement = await page.getElementByCss('h3 .amount');

  expect(+(await priceElement.getText()).replace(',', '')).toBeGreaterThan(0);
});
```

and in the test.po.ts file:

```
async setSelectBoxValueInsideChildComponent(formFieldName: string, value: string) {
   const formField = element(by.css(`[formControlName="${formFieldName}"] select`))
  .element(by.css(`option[value="${value}"]`));

   await formField.click();
}

 getElementByCss(selector: string) {
   return element(by.css(selector));
}
```

So this test file should be ran successfully. It actually has been running successfully several times. But sometimes, the line of "destination" throws an error and sometimes the "h3 .amount" line throws an error with no reason.

Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, option[value="xxx"])

And the screen just flash and exit very quickly. So I was not able to inspect what's going on.

I'm very confused. I shut down VS Code to solve the issue so far. But it really bugs me since once I modify something, the error might come back.

Please help! Thanks in advance!

BTW, how can we debug in VS Code for e2e testing? I have tried several suggestions from internet, nothing worked... :(

Comment: please show the functions: `setSelectBoxValueInsideChildComponent()` and `getElementByCss()`

Comment: Just added the two functions to my question. Thanks!

Comment: C, the two functions has no obvious issue,  the only possible reason i guess is you need to add some wait before the two functions. you can try that for debug purpose to prove my guess.  add `await browser.sleep(10*1000)`

Comment: Thanks Yong! I added the await browser.sleep(60*1000) to debug. Turns out, there is an error when the API try get countries. "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error". I'm confused. I can run my application via chrome perfectly. The countries always show. How come when doing test in e2e Protractor, it throws this error? Anyone knows? Thanks

Comment: which host do you use when you run via Chrome?

Comment: I'm running on localhost 4200. The error of "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' was gone after I restart VS Code.... I also figured out why the second one "h3 .amount" failed. It's the quote price coming from API. My localhost is slower than other developers. So I actually need to let the browser wait a couple of seconds to make sure the quote present. Somehow, the another solution of using "var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;" doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The error of "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' was gone after I restart VS Code.... I also figured out why the second one "h3 .amount" failed. It's the quote price coming from API. My localhost is slower than other developers. So I actually need to let the browser wait a couple of seconds to make sure the quote present. Somehow, the another solution of using "var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;" doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

to solve the problem of "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin" edit the file protractor.conf
And add `"--disable-web-security"` in args of chromeOptions.

should be kinda:

```
exports.config = {
  params: {
    test: 'hml'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  multiCapabilities: [
    {
      name: 'desktop',
      browserName: 'chrome',
      chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--disable-extensions --disable-web-security']
      },
      specs: ['./e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts', './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.dsk.ts']
    }
```